# USB Devices don't connect at the same time

Tags: linux, virtualbox, network-interface, usb-device

This problem is a bit weird and complex.
I recently installed linux on `virtualbox`.So when I run the system I can access websites from firefox using the `linux system`.At the same time I can access websites from `windows`.But the problem is when I type **iwconfig** in terminal I cannot find any `wlan` interface.I am supposed to get a wlan interface like `wlan0` as I have a `TP LINK network adapter`.
Now when I select my usb device from the `device>USB` I loosed internet connection from `windows`.After doing this I can't even access websites from linux.But now if I type **iwconfig** in the terminal I get a `wlan0 interface`.What is the problem?

Comment: The question does not describe your situation well. You should clarify which OS / Version you use as host and in the VM. And detail the technical characteristics of your usb wifi. Because there can be many causes (drivers, guest additions, usb 2.0 vs usb 3.0, nat, etc, etc)

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem.  You're just experiencing the fact that only one system can have control of a USB device at a time.  Your VM doesn't *have* a virtual wireless interface; it likely has a virtual *ethernet* interface.   On the VM settings, you will want to set the network setting to either "Bridged" (which will make it look to your network like the VM is just another host on the same segment) or "NAT" (which makes your host computer act as a router for the VM).  Leave your physical network interface under the control of the physical computer.